# PHP Class Extensions

Tags: php, class

I was just wondering if the next situation could be possible or not, I've read the PHP Manual documentation, but I would like another perspective because it's not so clear for me.

So I have for example one class:

```
class SomeClass {
    public function someFunction() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And an extension of it:

```
class Extension extends SomeClass {
    public function someOtherFunction() {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is, could I be able to use the public functions inside the classes on both ways, the main class's function inside the extended function and the other way around?

And would I be doing that how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `public` and `protected`functions of your parent in the extended (child) class:

```
class Extension extends SomeClass
{
    public function someOtherFunction() {
        $foo = $this->someFunction(); // from parent class
        return $foo;
    }
}
```

When class "Extension" is created, its basically a copy of "SomeClass" which you can modify in the way as you can add new functions or overwrite those of the parent class.

The parent does not know about the Extension (it can be extended multiple times, eg "JSONRequest extends Request", "XMLRequest extends Request"). Calling extended functions from within the parent makes no sense, since the parent class can never know which childs function it should call in such a situation. This type of Inheritance is one of the basic concepts of OOP and clear interfaces.

In other words, no it will never work the other way round. And it should not.

Comment: I see, so basically if I want to use the extended class's functions inside the main class I should better make an separate class. That is why I asked, but it seems there is no way around but making an separate class.

Comment: there is a way around. Why don't you just use your `SomeClass`?

Comment: You mean define the functions I need inside the SomeClass ? Yes, that would be a way, but I wanted to keep it separated, each of the class would have done something different, with no relation to each other.

Answer (score 3):

You can use both functions from class Extension, but only someFunction() from class SomeClass.

Extension does not change the original class, it just incorporates it into a new one.

Comment: Yes, Extension is in fact an extension of the main class, I understood that from the PHP manual, but what you're saying is that I can use `someFunction()` inside the extended class but I cannot use `someOtherFunction()` inside the main class ?

Comment: Exactly: Extension is a one-way process - the new class gets everything from the old class, but the old class gains nothing, it stays unchanged. So in your case the old class doesn't know about the new function.